# how can I read from a big file and insert it to a database in java in a fast way

Tags: java, mysql, database, performance

I have this text file with this format

```
int | string | string | string |
int | string | string | string |
int | string | string | string |
.
.
.
```

Size of this file is about 80 MB. I have to read this file and after some evaluation add it to the database.

What I do is that I read one line and based on some condition I add them to the database. But this code is taking so long. It's been literally more than a day that I ran this code and no result yet!

What can I do to make it faster.

I know there should be some way to read the whole file at once.

BTW I'm using mysql

Help me out guys!

Here is my code

```
public void fill_names_db() throws Exception{

    MySQLAccess dao = new MySQLAccess();   
    Scanner stringScanner;



    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\havij\\Downloads\\taxdump\\names.dmp"));

    String tax_id;
    String name_txt;
    String unique_name;
    String name_class;
    Connection connect=null;
    connect = dao.newConnection();



    while (in.ready()) {


        String s = in.readLine();
        //System.out.println(s);
        stringScanner = new Scanner(s).useDelimiter("\t|\t");

        tax_id = stringScanner.next();
        stringScanner.next();
        name_txt = stringScanner.next();
        stringScanner.next();
        unique_name = stringScanner.next();
        stringScanner.next();
        name_class = stringScanner.next();



        if(name_class.equals("scientific name"))
            dao.insertToDB(connect, "id_to_name", tax_id.toString(), name_txt);

        if(dao.hasKey(connect,"name_to_id",name_txt))
            if (!unique_name.isEmpty())
                dao.insertToDB(connect, "name_to_id",unique_name,tax_id.toString(),name_txt,unique_name, name_class );

        else if(!name_txt.isEmpty())
            dao.insertToDB(connect, "name_to_id",name_txt,tax_id.toString(),name_txt,unique_name, name_class );


    }
    dao.close(connect);
    in.close();
    System.out.println("done");

    }
```

Comment: Do you know if you are auto-committing? Batching up calls to the database will help.

Comment: @nattyddubbs I'm not familiar with auto-committing. I simply just insert a row to a table.

Comment: @nattyddubbs it still shouldn't take _that_ long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file is already well formatted for using the MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE directive. You can read up on it here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/load-data.html

You would just need to use '|' as your field delimiter and \n as your line delimiter.

Don't forget the LOCAL keyword, since the file is probably located on the SQL Client's filesystem.

Comment: Doesn't quite work, as the OP is loading to multiple tables, one of which seems to require duplicate removal.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't want the overhead of Java in this instance.  You want to use what is known as [load data infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019506/importing-csv-using-load-data-infile-quote-problem):

```
mysql> create table t2 (a varchar(20), b varchar(20), c varchar(20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> load data infile '/tmp/data.csv' into table t2 fields terminated by ','   
       enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n' (a, b, c);
```

and [security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421312/mysql-load-data-infile)

Comment: I would add the `local` keyword to your solution: `load data local infile ...`

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out your task will be done easier using the load data infile. If you insist on doing that in Java try to use the `BufferedReader` constructor that allows you to specify the buffer size e.g.

```
// specify 128K buffer, default is 8K
// You can try larger values, it really depends on your disk I/O
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\havij\\Downloads\\taxdump\\names.dmp"), 128 * 1024);
```

Be aware of an additional issue: the apparoach you take with the `FileReader` may corrupt your data if the file contains UTF8 characters. It is better to use an `InputStreamReader` and specify the character set used by your file